# Rails: Use custom class for activerecord attribute (update in place)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I have a jsonb column activerecord returns the attribute as a hash but somehow retains a reference to that object so it is able to detect changes.  That is, code behaves like the following

```
pub = Publication.find("554a1791-e690-4a45-8207-db6b66fa3480")
md = pub.metadata #jsonb column
pub.metadata_changed?  #false
md['foo'] = 'bar'
pub.metadata_changed?  #true
```

I'd like to replace the hash class with an instance of a custom class but retain the modification in place behavior.  What do I need to do to achieve this?  Do I overload some kind of method to check if the object is dirty?

Comment: Check out the store_accessor https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html -- it lets you access the goodies in the column's hash with an object interface.